# Update a cross object picklist field

Tags: process-builder

I have a Standard pick-list field on Accounts Called "Type" and i have another Custom pick-list field called "Business unit" on the object called "Asset Tag". There is no master-detail relation ship between these objects. But there is a look-up relationship on the "Asset Tag" object. So whenever i save an Asset Tag record with type pick-list value as "EV". I want update the "Account type" pick-list field value to "EV".

I looked in to few portals and found out that we can do it using process builder and the i started to build a process. But i am stuck in the middle.

[image]

I don't know what to do next. Because I want the account record to update. But it is asking me further select another object's record.

What should i modify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Toggle back to "Select the Account record that started your process"
2. Click back on "Select a record related to the sme1__blah checkbox"
3. **Important:** instead of clicking the drop down search for Account String, it should show you 2 options as below, one with > arrow and one without '>' arrow. choose the one without '>' and click Choose
4. From there you can drill down into Account fields and set the type. Make sure you switch the Type* from "String" to "Reference" to access the sme1__blah object fields.

   [image: Select a record related to the contact]

Comment: Hey I was able to figure out the issue. I found Account Below it. Everything is working fine. Thank you. Rao